# Find all dependent maven projects

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

In our project we have the following dependency structure:

```
import-api <--- import-parent <--- importer-xyz (multiple importer projects)
```

Now I want to find all importer projects using a specific`import-api`(or import-parent) version. To be clearer each importer-project does have the`import-parent`project as parent and does have a`import-api`dependency in the version as provided by the`import-parent`dependency-management section.

Is there a maven-plugin or another tool that can resolve those dependent projects?

Comment: Unclear, what do you want to do exactly? Are those dependencies?

Comment: @Tunaki I have extended my explanation. Is it now clearer to you?

Comment: Yes thank you :). But I don't think you can do that reliably really...

Comment: AFAIK Maven doesn't do reverse dependency mapping. Maybe a repository manager holding all your artifacts can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can expect Maven to have a plugin, as Maven has no "super view" of all the Maven projects you have created.

For a smallish set of projects, open them all in an IDE and do a simple text search on artifact name.

For a large set of projects, you may be able to create some scripts that do a text search of your source code repository.

Good luck!